# :nth-child for a class not starting at 1

Tags: jquery

I'm learning jQuery, and I still haven't got the hang of how `:nth-child` works yet. I am trying to make a div disappear when I click the first iteration of class: `imgDescription`. Strangely, jQuery interprets 2 as the first child. When I switched this for `$('imgDescription:eq(0)')` the script worked as expected. Does anyone know why nth-child works this way?

```js
$('.imgDescription:nth-child(2)').click(function() {
  $('div').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 class="btn-primary">Learn More about Our Services</h2>
<div id="centershit">
  <br>
  <div class="imgDescription"><span><a href="#socialmedia">Social Media</a></span>
    <div class="imgcontainer">
      <img src="pics/twitter.jpeg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="imgDescription"><span><a href="#healthcare">Healthcare</a></span>
    <div class="imgcontainer">
      <img src="pics/health.png">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="imgDescription"><span><a href="#email">Email</a></span>
    <div class="imgcontainer">
      <img src="pics/gmail.png">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="imgDescription"><span><a href="#socialmedia">Online Shopping</a></span>
    <div class="imgcontainer">
      <img src="pics/amazon.png">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="imgDescription"><span><a href="#socialmedia">Web Browsing</a></span>
    <div class="imgcontainer">
      <img src="pics/googling.png">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="imgDescription"><span><a href="#device">Devices</a></span>
    <div class="imgcontainer">
      <img onClick="expanddevice()" src="pics/device.png">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Read API https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/ `the value of n is "1-indexed",`

Comment: yes, but why did the first element only respond with :nth-child(2)?

Comment: Again `Selects all elements that are the nth-child of their parent.` In your HTML `br` is first element of parent `.centershit`

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `<br>` from your `centershit` div and your code works fine as you wanted it to work. As it is treating `<br>` as the first child of the `centershit` class

```js
$('.imgDescription:nth-child(2)').click(function() {
  $('div').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 class="btn-primary">Learn More about Our Services</h2>
<div id="centershit">
  <div class="imgDescription"><span><a href="#socialmedia">Social Media</a></span>
    <div class="imgcontainer">
      <img src="pics/twitter.jpeg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="imgDescription"><span><a href="#healthcare">Healthcare</a></span>
    <div class="imgcontainer">
      <img src="pics/health.png">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="imgDescription"><span><a href="#email">Email</a></span>
    <div class="imgcontainer">
      <img src="pics/gmail.png">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="imgDescription"><span><a href="#socialmedia">Online Shopping</a></span>
    <div class="imgcontainer">
      <img src="pics/amazon.png">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="imgDescription"><span><a href="#socialmedia">Web Browsing</a></span>
    <div class="imgcontainer">
      <img src="pics/googling.png">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="imgDescription"><span><a href="#device">Devices</a></span>
    <div class="imgcontainer">
      <img onClick="expanddevice()" src="pics/device.png">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```